# Gettng a segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault on the execution of the code below.The program compiles successfully ,but gives an error on execution.
What is a segmentation fault and how to correct it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include "sel.h"
#include<sys/time.h>
main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    struct timeval t1,t2;
    struct timezone tz;
    int i,n;
    int *a;

    char *num;
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned long long time1,time2;

    fp=fopen("file1.txt","w");
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&n);
    a=(int*)malloc (sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=n;i>0;i--)
    {
        sprintf(num,"%d\n",i);
        fputs(num,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");
    i=0;
    while(fgets(num,255,fp)!=NULL)
    {
        sscanf(num,"%d",&a[i++]);
    }

    gettimeofday(&t1,&tz);
    time1=t1.tv_sec*1000000+t1.tv_usec;
    sel(a,n);
    gettimeofday(&t2,&tz);
    time2=t2.tv_sec*1000000+t2.tv_usec;
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("file2","w");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sprintf(num,"%d\n",a[i]);
        fputs(num,fp);
    }
    free(a);
    printf("\n %llu",time2-time1);
}
```

Comment: Why did you rollback? Is it not C?  The language tag is necessary, and don't use bold font everywhere.

Comment: there are a lot of things that could go wrong in your code e.g. you dont check how many command line arguments there, you forgot to include stdlib.h for malloc, you dont check return values of c-runtime functions... also you should make sure 'n' is well defined since you use it to allocate space. always initialize all variables and finally learn to use a debugger, it is a skill you need as a programmer.

Comment: @CyberSpock The code was running fine; problems started when i included the gettimeofday function to compute the time taken by sel().

Comment: The fact that your code worked before, doesn't mean that it was ok. It just means that your compiler didn't find anything and that you were unlucky, so it didn't crash. Do you use maximum warning levels for your compiler (e.g `-Wall`)?

Answer (score 2):

Segmentation fault means you had a bad memory access.  In this case, you never allocated any memory for `num`, so you are writing to an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: memory is allocated to num when a value is allocated to it in the sprintf function

Comment: @jasrajbedi No, `sprintf` does not allocate memory.

Comment: If so, it's a non-standard sprintf().

Comment: ..and would have to have num passed by reference, eg, '&num'.

Comment: i can't understand the situation.Can any one suggest a correction?